# How do I send data to another page and redirect to yet another page?

Tags: jquery, forms, post, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm using ASP.NET Web Pages 3 and JQuery 2.1.

I have a web page Input.cshtml and all of it is html, no server side code. I also have a page called ShowTable.cshtml and all of it is html, no server side code. And lastly, a page called LoadTable.cshtml (all server side code) that, using JQuery, populates the table.

What I want to do is: take the input from Input.cshtml and pass it to LoadTable.cshtml, then have LoadTable.cshtml pass the resulting data to ShowTable.cshtml. All my postback and ajax is done through JQuery. Put another way, I want to pass the input from one web page to a server-side page and have that server-side page send the resulting data to a different web page.

I have most of this done. The only part I'm stumped at is getting the server-side page to send the resulting data to a different web page.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is the inherit statelessness of the web, but there are a few options available:

```
Http Cache:
```

If the data can be shared between all users I would consider the http cache to store it

```
SessionState:
```

Store the values in SessionState in the original page and refer back to it in any subsequent pages. This is a common option in scenarios where the data is specific to a user.

```
Html5 local storage:
```

Store the values in local storage on the client. This is not a good option if we're talking about large amounts of data though since you have to transfer it to the client. A variation on this is Session storage which uses a similar API, but is only valid for the current browser session.

```
Url:
```

Pass the data in the url's query string. This will have limitations due to max url size etc.

```
Post Request:
```

To get around the limitation of passing data in the url you can post it to the other page through the post data of a post request.

Comment: Is there a way to use hidden fields in this?

Comment: The hidden field is unique to a single page though, but it is fine to store values in hidden fields and post the values to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want to do is store the items in a database (MySQL, MongoDB etc.) on page 1. Once in the DB you can access the items using `$.ajax`or `$.get` from either page 2 or page 3. *Personally speaking, I always use Databases when 3 page interactions are needed.*

You can do similar 3 page interactions with session data stored on the client's computer as @TGH has suggested. However, if you do take this route (and depending on what you're doing with the information you need to load) I'd be weary of storing long term user input this way since you're going to have to post the values to your server page but you still have to read them from the client's host computer when you reach your page 3 (i.e. the page which didn't receive the post information directly).

If you do use session storage you may wish to limit the expiry date of the cookie (if you choose to use jQuery cookies for example), and remember that `localStorage` items have no expiry date so if you choose `localStorage` as your option you can set the items to `null` if you need to destroy them.

Comment: The input doesn't need to be persisted just passed to the server-side script so it can generate the necessary data.

Comment: @dotnetN00b might want to go with session storage in that case. Just expire or set the items to null after you're done with the data

Comment: Alternatively, you probably can just do 2 post requests in your on submit function from page 1. Post to page 2, then again to page 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you want to use a third page for displaying your output.

When you post your data from Input.cshtml to LoadTable.cshtml, it responds back to Input.cshtml and you have to find a way to transfer the response to ShowTable. Why don't you use a single page for input and display data, hiding in turn the part that doesn't matter?

In the code that follows I have simulated a simple application that posts data to a table Temp with only Id, FirstName and LastName fields and displays the content of the table:

LoadTable.cshtml

```
@using System.Text;

@{
    if(IsPost){
        var db = Database.Open("MyDb");
        var sql = "INSERT INTO Temp (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@0, @1)";
        var FirstName = Request["FirstName"];
        var LastName = Request["LastName"];
        db.Execute(sql, FirstName, LastName);

        var data = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Temp");
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<table>");
        html.Append("<tr><th>id</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>");
        foreach(var row in data){
            html.Append("<tr><td>" + row.id + "</td><td>" + row.FirstName + 
                    "</td><td>" + row.LastName + "</td>");
        }
        html.Append("</table>");

        Response.Write(html.ToString());
    }
}
```

Input.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <form method="post" id="myForm" action="~/LoadTable.cshtml">
                FirstName: <input type="text" name="FirstName" /><br />
                LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName" /><br />
            </form>
            <button onclick="GetHtml()">Display</button>
        </div>
        <div id="display">
            <button onclick="GetForm()">Input</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(function () {
        GetForm();
    });

    function GetHtml() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#myForm").attr('action'),
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "<button onclick='GetForm()'>Input</button>";
                $("#display").prepend(data);
                $("#form").hide();
                $("#display").show();
            }
        });
    }

    function GetForm() {
        $("input:text").val("");
        $("#display").hide();
        $("#form").show();
    }
</script>
```

I hope it helps.